# Python tkinter - place function not working with multiple widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

When making a program for a game database, I want to have the main menu to have multiple buttons leading to multiple topics. The place function isn't working for me. Here is my code:

```
windowFU = tk.Tk()
windowFU.title("MHFU Database")
windowFU.geometry("255x200+300+180")

frame = tk.Frame(master = windowFU, width = 255, height = 200)
frame.pack()

icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = "images/icon.png")
windowFU.iconphoto(False, icon)

welcome = tk.Label(

    master = frame,
    text = "What would you like to view?",
    width = 30,
    height = 2

)

searchEntry = tk.Entry(

    master = frame,
    width = 30

)

buttonMonstersFU = tk.Button(

    master = frame,
    text = "Monsters",
    width = 12,
    height = 2

)

# Here is the place function
buttonMonstersFU.place(x = 100, y = 100)

welcome.pack()
searchEntry.pack()
buttonMonstersFU.pack()

searchEntry.bind('<Return>', getEntry)

windowFU.mainloop()
```

Note: Currently I just have the place function set to `x = 100, y = 100` to test, it is not my final location.

Here is an image of what I get:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbZ5c.png)

What should I do?

Comment: it seems to work. oh the issue: because You are packing the button not placing it; don't use `.pack()` it will override the `.place()` function and tkinter will just pack it instead of placing it, also there is no really a need to place them, is there? since You can still put multiple buttons very effectively using `.pack()` or `.grid()` or both (on different frames for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `buttonMonstersFU.pack()` a few lines after you call `buttonMonsersFU.place(...)`. Only one of `pack`, `place`, or `grid` can be responsible for a widget. When you call `pack`, any work done by `place` will be thrown away.

If you want to use `place`, then remove the line that calls `buttonMonstersFU.pack()`.